# Flutter Error: A RenderFlex was mutated in RenderSliverList.performLayout

Tags: android, flutter

I am building the sizedbox in flutter as below code which has a Stepper, but it is giving display error of RenderFlex, how should I resolve it? this error happened when i navigate from this specific page, this code is from the navigation to specific page in navbar

```
ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.notification_add),
              title: const Text('List of Recorded Inspection'),
              onTap: () {
                
            Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => BlocProvider<DatasendBloc>.value(
                      value: _PostingBloc,
                      child: const SaveformApp(),
                    ),
                  ));
          
              }
            ),
```

and this is navigating to the said page which error occured

```
ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.ad_units),
              title: const Text('List of Prepared Inspection'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const PrepPage(title: 'List of Saved IDs',))
            );
              },
            ),
```

and this is content of said pages,

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200.0,
              child: Stepper(
                physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                type: StepperType.vertical,
                controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails controls) {
                  return const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                  );
                },
                onStepTapped: (step) => setState(() => _currentStep = step),
                onStepContinue: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_currentStep < _steps().length - 1) {
                      _currentStep += 1;
                    } else {
                      _currentStep = 0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                onStepCancel: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (_currentStep > 0) {
                      _currentStep -= 1;
                    } else {
                      _currentStep = 0;
                    }
                  });
                },
                currentStep: _currentStep,
                steps: _steps(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

i already add expanded class and put its height but the same error is still occured, how do i fix this??

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).